# Derive daily delta from total daily counts? Tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns:

```
ID, 
tableName, 
totalRowCount, 
Date
```

Each day I'm appending the number of rows in the relevant table. What I want to do is create a table which has the number of new rows created on each table each day. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a table for this? Can't you just query it? Better not to store redundant information.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for SQL Server 2012 or later version, you could use [the LAG analytic function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to produce the required result:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  tableName,
  rowCountDelta = totalRowCount - LAG(totalRowCount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY tableName
                                                                     ORDER BY Date),
  Date
FROM
  dbo.yourTable
;
```

The above query assumes that the first entry in a partition is indeed the very first addition of rows. (`LAG(totalRowCount, 1, 0)` means the absence of the previous `totalRowCount` will be treated as a zero.) If that cannot be assumed safely in every case and you would prefer to return NULL for first entries, you could use just `LAG(totalRowCount) OVER ...` instead:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  tableName,
  rowCountDelta = totalRowCount - LAG(totalRowCount) OVER (PARTITION BY tableName
                                                               ORDER BY Date),
  Date
FROM
  dbo.yourTable
;
```

If you insist on storing the results in a table, you can just add an INTO clause to the query. A possibly better idea, though, might be to save the query as a view.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for posting the obvious, but you could add a T-SQL statement that runs whenever you populate your table, if this is at all feasible:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --- Insert goes here:
    INSERT INTO dbo.someTable (a, b, c)
    SELECT a, b, c FROM anotherTable;

    --- .. and log it to the row count table:
    INSERT INTO dbo.rowCountTable (tableName, totalRowCount, Date)
    VALUES ('someTable', @@ROWCOUNT, GETDATE());

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```